# How to create a React onClick with a HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using Google Map API to create an app. In order to render the text in the bubble when you click on a marker in the app you have to make an HTML string.

IE:

```
const markerBubble = '<div class="marker-wrapper">' +
  `<div class="marker-title">${locations[i][0]}</div>` +
  `<div class="marker-view-btn">View</div>` +
'</div>';
```

As you can see I can render the title dynamically. But, I have button in there that I want to use to push the page (also using React Router). I can't do

`<Link><div class="marker-view-btn">View</div></Link>`

because the `Link` doesn't render correctly. How would I go about adding an `onClick` to this div?

Comment: The normal way: `<div class="marker-view-btn" onClick={this.handleClick}>View</div>`

Comment: Does <button class="maker-view-btn" onClick={this.linkTo}>View</button> works for you?

Comment: @vijayst onClick doesn't work because this is regular HTML and not JSX. When I inspect the element it has an `onclick` (it is all lower case when you inspect) property on it. When you inspect an element that is JSX it won't show their `onClick` property when you inspect with devtools. All in all, this solution does not work

Comment: ^ @MattYao read above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push the page on different component/route you could do this using '`Link`' component of `react-router v4.0`.

```
<Link className="marker-view-btn" to='/newDestination'>View</Link>
```

where, `/newDestination` is your new route where you want to go on click of '`View`'.

Comment: Not using React v4, using v3. Also, as I said, because it's HTML and not JSX it won't render the `Link` tag correctly. Will show as a lowercase `l`, `link` which won't actually work. As you know, `Link` isn't actually a HTML element, it will transform into an `<a>` tag